# Placing Labels above UISlider using UIStackView

Tags: ios, autolayout, storyboard, uilabel, uistackview

We are trying to find storyboard-only solution for the following scenario:

We want to set "milestones"/"steps" labels above UISlider. The thumb location at value of 0.2 should be exactly at the middle of the correspond labels above it. It's important that the labels positions will adapt depends on the screen, so the constraints needs to be some what proportional. Illustration:

[image]

**What we tried:**

We position UIStackView with 7 arranged subviews (One for each step) above the Slider, and made it a little bit wider (1.14x of the Slider width, which is 1/7 bigger on purpose). For some reason it aligns for some steps and not align for others. Sample:

[image]

[image]

**Any suggestions or advice in the right why to solve it, would be highly appreciated. Thank you!**

**Best Regards, Roi**

Comment: I think you should create your own slider control

Comment: Hey @ReinierMelian thank for replying. I thought about it, but I'm pretty sure it's solvable, and it's an overkill to build complete new one just to place labels above it (which doesn't effects the touch events, it's only UI related labels)

Comment: you need to take in account the thumb width, I think that adding (thumb width)/2 as space before start and and after the end

Comment: As the stack width constraint constant? @ReinierMelian

Comment: its possible, as leading and trailing pined to the slider

Comment: let me know if solves your issue

Comment: @ReinierMelian Checking now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166921/discussion-between-roi-mulia-and-reinier-melian).

Comment: @ReinierMelian +1, A custom `UIControl` composed by `UILabel` and `UISlider`, and override it's `layoutSubviews` method to reposition those `UILabel`.

Answer (score 2):

[**Complete Playground source available here**](https://gist.github.com/jmcd/2499a901136df6f5c327216b27e4e6d4)

[image]

If you subclass `UISlider`, you can override the [`thumbRect(forBounds:trackRect:value:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uislider/1621344-thumbrect) method, which allows you to adjust the rectangle that the thumb-image is displayed in. Do that, and make it so that the thumb-image is positioned with its centre on the corresponding point on the track.

```
override func thumbRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect, trackRect rect: CGRect, value: Float) -> CGRect {
    let superThumbRect = super.thumbRect(forBounds: bounds, trackRect: rect, value: value)
    let valueAsDecimalFraction = value == minimumValue ? 0 : (value - minimumValue)/(maximumValue - minimumValue)
    let valueAsDecimalFractionOfMinusOneToOne = (valueAsDecimalFraction*2 - 1)/2
    let xOffset = CGFloat(valueAsDecimalFractionOfMinusOneToOne) * superThumbRect.width
    return CGRect(
        x: superThumbRect.origin.x + xOffset,
        y: superThumbRect.origin.y,
        width: superThumbRect.size.width,
        height: superThumbRect.size.height)
}
```

Once you have overriden [`thumbRect(forBounds:trackRect:value:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uislider/1621344-thumbrect), you will see that the thumb-image now has the correct behaviour, except now it hangs outside the view when the slider is at min or max values. To correct for this, override the [`trackRect(forBounds:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uislider/1621349-trackrect) method, so that the track is padded by some value that allows the thumb-image to remain inside the slider bounds.

```
let padding = CGFloat(18)

override func trackRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    let superTrackRect = super.trackRect(forBounds: bounds)
    return CGRect(
        x: superTrackRect.origin.x + padding,
        y: superTrackRect.origin.y,
        width: superTrackRect.size.width - padding*2,
        height: superTrackRect.size.height)
}
```

You will probably struggle to position the `UILabel`s using a `UIStackView` – the centre points of the labels will not be in the correct location. Instead, layout the labels with constraints relative to the slider.

```
// Assuming labels: [UILabel], and a value of thumbIndent

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    let labelConstraints = labels.enumerated().map { (i, label) -> [NSLayoutConstraint] in
        let pct = CGFloat(i)/CGFloat(labels.count-1)
        let centerX = (view.bounds.size.width-2*thumbIndent) * pct + thumbIndent
        return [
            label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: slider.leftAnchor, constant: centerX),
            label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: slider.topAnchor, constant: 0),
        ]
        }.flatMap { $0 }
        .
        .
        .
}
```